# Google Analytics reverse transaction not working with sales performance

Tags: google-analytics

We have Google Analytics account and trying to do reverse transaction.
We have created a transaction on one date and reverse transaction on some other date.
After transaction if we do reverse transaction it disappears from transactions list.
Is it the expected behavior or abnormal behavior?

But, if we check the same order data in sales performance, the reverse transaction does not
reflects on when we created the transaction, it reflecting on when we made reverse transaction date.
It should not be like this. The reverse transaction should affect the same date on when we made the transaction.

Comment: What we need to do get sales performance get affect on the same day of transaction which we made, if we do reverse transaction for the same order

Comment: Any update on this plz.., itz urgent................

Comment: According to Google Documentation there is no way this could work like you want it to (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en&ref_topic=1037062).

Comment: I have tried this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493455/Server-side-Google-Analytics-Transactions...  Every thing works out but not my requirement

Comment: That's because there is no way to send a timestamp - if you pull the data via API access you'll see that Google stores actually multiple transaction with the same Orderid (even if you get a consolidated view in the interface) unless you send the original and the changed transaction on the same day.