# Can I remove a transaction from Google Analytics a few days later?

Tags: google-analytics

So the long story short is there was a bug on a production site [which has since been fixed] that caused a transaction to be logged for ~1000x its actual value.

Ideally I'd like to either change the price for that transaction but in lieu of that I'd be happy to just remove it all together.

It is a single transaction and it happened a few days ago so I can't just run a negative priced second transaction to average it out.

Comment: See also: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54932/google-analytics-reverse-transaction-not-working-with-sales-performance which is a very similar question (without any answers yet)

Answer (score 1):

I've never found a way to delete or edit previous transactions - only run a negative one as you suggest but that doesn't really help.

What you could do, although it isn't ideal for many reasons, is setup an advanced segment which ignores that transaction ID. It does mean you have to choose to view the data with that segment every time you want to look at the data but it is at least one option.

Comment: I've been reading that this is the solution, but I'm not sure why my attempt isn't working. I checked all the fields. If you have experience in implementing a reversal, I'd really appreciate your input. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277303/reversing-a-google-analytics-ecommerce-transaction

Comment: in 2015, if you enter the information properly (negative numbers except for price, all items, and same transaction id, it truly reverses the order as if it never happened). But for some orders, I'm running into bugs of that not happening.